# Debugging Java Swing App causes computer freeze

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, debugging, freeze

I'm developing a Java/Swing Desktop app on XUbuntu using Eclipse2018-12. I'm facing a problem when debugging. When Eclipse reaches a breakpoint in the **addItemListener** event of a **JComboBox**, all freezes, including the computer...

I thought it was linked to the Java installation and the debug configuration, so I tried by changing the version of the JRE used but nothing changed.

Here is the code of the

```java
JComboBox<ComboItem> res = new JComboBox<ComboItem>();
        res.addItemListener(new ItemListener() {
            @Override
            public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent event) {
                if (event.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.SELECTED && peopleCombo != null) {
                                           //do things
                    }
                }
            }    
        });
        return res;
```

Here is the java version.

```
java --version
openjdk 11.0.2 2019-01-15
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.2+9-Ubuntu-3ubuntu118.04.3)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 11.0.2+9-Ubuntu-3ubuntu118.04.3, mixed mode, sharing)
```

Should I change this event ? Or the java version used ?

Thanks for your help,

Baptiste

Comment: Please post [mcve]. 

I find mcve a very useful technique. Not only it makes helping much easier, it 
is a powerful debugging tool. It many case, while preparing one, you are likely to find the problem.

Comment: For those that have the problem : had this parameter in the degub config. -Dsun.awt.disablegrab=true

Comment: Consider posting an answer to your own question.

Answer (score 5):

For those that have the problem, add this parameter in the debug config:

```
-Dsun.awt.disablegrab=true
```

Comment: Also you can set environment variable like

export _JAVA_OPTIONS='-Dsun.awt.disablegrab=true'

Comment: I thought this was something unavoidable, like the inability to take screenshots with any menu, context menu or combobox open (in any program) without using the screenshot app and using the delay option. Glad someone found a workaround, at least for Java programs.